# Cannot Remove Multiple Classes

Tags: jquery

I want to remove two classes from a div when a user clicks another div.

Here's the jQuery I used:

```
jQuery('#toggle-delivery').on('click', function(){
    jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").removeClass("collapsed checkout-acc-disabled");
jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").removeClass("checkout-disable-icon");
} );
```

For some reason, the `collapsed` class is not removed. The above only removes `checkout-acc-disabled`.

I also tried this, and I get the same results:

```
jQuery('#toggle-delivery').click( function() {
    jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").removeClass('collapsed checkout-acc-disabled');
jQuery("#checkout-accordion-delivery").removeClass("checkout-disable-icon");
} );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class added by a library you're using?

Comment: Did you try removing one class then removing the other (so two lines of code)? BTW, I don't see a difference between the two code samples in the post.

Comment: I think Bootstrap JS.

Comment: @MikeS One uses `on('click', function(){` and the other uses `click( function() {`. Anyway, I tried removing one class and then the other. Same result.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: OK, fixed it with `jQuery('#collapse-delivery').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
jQuery("#panel-delivery-heading").removeClass("collapsed");
} );` I forgot `show.bs.collapse` fires the next panel.